# In SQL database,how to use one column with different condition values pair with another column with different conditions values?

Tags: mysql

My database design is like image shows:

[image]

The data table is design for a survey's all respondent's answers. The query I need is, for example,

I want to know all RID(Respondent ID) that has conditions of QID = 2 and Answers = 26-35, and QID = 4 and Answers = "ASHFIELD". But the sql query below:

```
select * from RespondentAnswers
where (QID = 2 and Answers = '26-35') and (QID = 4 and Answers = 'ASHFIELD')
```

was obvious not correct.

In short, I want to know those respondents who is age from '26-35' and living in 'ASHFIELD'.

My database structure was showed in the image above. Any one has solution please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be using a group by an having

```
select rid 
from RespondentAnswers
where (QID , Answers ) in ( (2, '26-35'),  (4,'ASHFIELD'))
group by rid 
having  count(*) =2;
```

Comment: Still get errors ------> Error -2147217900 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @scaisEdge suggestion, based on it I figured out a possible correct answer, which may help other people who encountering the same issue:

select RID 
from RespondentAnswers
where QID in (2,4) and Answers in ('26-35', 'ASHFIELD')
group by RID 
having  count(*) =2;

I already tested on many conditions and all works fine, hope this is the correct answer I need.